# Zend Framework 2: Differences between ActionController and RestfulController

Tags: php, class, namespaces, zend-framework2

I am playing with the new Zend Framework 2 beta.

My question is:
What are the differences between these two namespaces/classes:

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
Zend\Mvc\Controller\RestfulController
```

In which way the last one is restful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Restful or Representational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) state transfer is a http standard which helps machines(clients and servers) talk to each other. While Restful implementation in some php frameworks like nooku is native and every form/view is automagically built on Rest, you will need alot to consider to implement Rest in your ZF project. While you could use Rest for all your controllers, for saving time and hassle, i recommend you only use Rest for your API.

RestfulController implements CRUD functions(Create Update Delete) which are not available in ActionController.

EDIT: Please have a look to [this great tutorial](http://www.techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework) on how to implement REST into your project and understand the principles.

Comment: Thanks! How do the CRUD functions work and why are they useful?

Comment: updated the answer.why exactly you are trying to use REST? REST is a complicated matter and needs lots of study.First you need to understand the concept.

Comment: Thank you for the link of the tutorial. I don't try to use REST. I want to write my web application using the BEST solutions. That's why I want to learn about REST and then decide wheather it makes sense or not for me. I will study the tutorial now. :-)